# What is input/output from fetched Graphql Schema and how to deal with it type-wise?

Tags: graphql-js, graphql-codegen

I use codegen to fetch and generate GraphQL schema in client Nextjs application. When I generate it, a lot of `[input]` and `[output]` types (?) are added to `Scalar` types, for example:

```
id: Scalars['Int']['input'];
approved?: InputMaybe<Scalars['Boolean']['output']>;
```

After fetching the schema typecheck fails in some places, mostly for ids, e.g.

```
 Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input: any; output: any; }'
```

If I remove all `[output]` and `[input]` types, typecheck doesn't fail.

**So, why are `[output]` and `[input]` needed in schema and why does typecheck fails with them but doesn't without?**

Answer (score 0):

Basically a Scalar can have a different type if it is used as an input or an output. That's why this change was introduced. This is a breaking change as it requires that each time you use Scalar['xxx'] as type to append either an ['input'] or ['output'] depending on the variable usage.

You can read more about that and the motivation there : https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/pull/9375